# Function of Optional Trailing Slash

Tags: html, trailing-slash

Can anyone give me a brief introduction to the "Optional trailing slash" and its function in HTML?
in the guide I am following it just says that it is optional and has no function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mostly to help you; to signify that you intended this particular element not to have a separate closing tag.